# Spring MVC - how to redirect to login if not logged in

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I am making updates to our web application adding a new user role that only has access to certain pages. Before this update, anytime a user was logged in and their session expired and the page was refreshed the login screen would appear. Now it attempts to load the page causing a null pointer exception because they aren't logged in and none of the data can be loaded.

Here is my config that I have been working on

```
    http.csrf().ignoringAntMatchers("/notification/**");
    http.csrf().ignoringAntMatchers("/embed/**/apply");
    http.csrf().ignoringAntMatchers("/view/**/apply");
    http.csrf().ignoringAntMatchers("/login");
    http.csrf().ignoringAntMatchers("/logout");
    http.csrf().ignoringAntMatchers("/register");

    http.authorizeRequests()

            .antMatchers("/").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/index").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/static/**").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/assets/**").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/register").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/skillRequest/**").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/skillRequest/skillFormUpdate/**").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/password/reset").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/password/reset/complete").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/email/verify").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/view/**").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/embed/**").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/dashboard").fullyAuthenticated()
            .antMatchers("/profile").fullyAuthenticated()
            .antMatchers("/candidate-profile/**").fullyAuthenticated()
            .antMatchers("/users.json").fullyAuthenticated()
            .antMatchers("/candidate/**/add").fullyAuthenticated()
            .antMatchers("/candidate/**/edit").fullyAuthenticated()
            .antMatchers("/**").not().hasAnyAuthority("ROLE_CANDIDATE")
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
            .formLogin()
            .loginPage("/login")
            .defaultSuccessUrl("/dashboard", false) //Force user to always go to the home page.  
           //.successHandler(successHandler())
            .permitAll()
            .and()
            .httpBasic()
            .and()
            .logout()
            .permitAll();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know, and maybe it sounds stupid, if this is the answer you are looking for, I am also new to Spring Boot and relatively new to Spring MVC, but as far as I have found out, and that is very simple solution, which maybe does not apply for big projects:

1. For all pages without access restriction, it does not make sense redirecting to login
2. For those functions that redirect to restricted pages, I have just added an annotation @PreAuthorize("hasAnyRole('ADMIN')"),     @PreAuthorize("hasAnyRole('ADMIN, USER')") or     @PreAuthorize("hasAnyRole('USER')") depending which role has access to the page.

Together with the Authentication Mechanism this does exactly what you asked for.

Answer (score 1):

I have used this xml config to redirect to login page,

```
<security:session-management invalid-session-url="/login" session-authentication-error-url="/login" session-fixation-protection="newSession">
            <security:concurrency-control error-if-maximum-exceeded="true" max-sessions="1" expired-url="/login"/>
        </security:session-management>
```

Comment: what XML config does this go into? web.xml?

Comment: You should be able to add same configuration in your config class